# ValueError while creating exe using cx_Freeze including PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I am trying to create *.exe* using cx_Freeze. When I try to build it, it throws a value error. I am not understanding what it means exactly. Do you think re-installing cx_Freeze could solve the problem?

*setup.py* is as it follows:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

exe = [Executable("main.py", base=base)]

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6'

options = {
'build_exe': {
    'includes': ['scipy.io', 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'],
    'include_files': [r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll', r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll',
                      r'C:\\Users\\dm\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyqt5_tools\\platforms\\qwindows.dll'],
    'packages': ['pandas', 'numpy', 'scipy', 'pydub', 'librosa', 'PyQt5.QtCore', 'PyQt5.QtGui', 'PyQt5.QtWidgets',
                 'python_speech_features'],
    }
}

setup(name="GUI", version="1.0", description='To be added',
  options=options, executables=exe)
```

While building it, I am getting the following error.

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 38, in <module>
options=options, executables=exe)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 616, in Freeze
self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 340, in _GetModuleFinder
finder.IncludeModule(name)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 651, in IncludeModule
namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 311, in _ImportModule
deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 385, in _InternalImportModule
namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 417, in _LoadModule
namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 486, in _LoadPackage
self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 464, in _LoadModule
self._RunHook("load", module.name, module)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 537, in _RunHook
method(self, *args)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 567, in load_scipy
finder.IncludePackage("scipy.misc")
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 659, in IncludePackage
module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 311, in _ImportModule
deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 417, in _LoadModule
namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 486, in _LoadPackage
self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 475, in _LoadModule
self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 565, in _ScanCode
module, relativeImportIndex)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 346, in _ImportModule
deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 475, in _LoadModule
self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 570, in _ScanCode
fromList, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 211, in _EnsureFromList
self._ImportModule(subModuleName, deferredImports, caller)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 311, in _ImportModule
deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 475, in _LoadModule
self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 589, in _ScanCode
topLevel = False)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 589, in _ScanCode
topLevel = False)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 570, in _ScanCode
fromList, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 211, in _EnsureFromList
self._ImportModule(subModuleName, deferredImports, caller)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 311, in _ImportModule
deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 475, in _LoadModule
self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 565, in _ScanCode
module, relativeImportIndex)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 311, in _ImportModule
deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 404, in _InternalImportModule
parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 464, in _LoadModule
self._RunHook("load", module.name, module)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 537, in _RunHook
method(self, *args)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 526, in load_PyQt4_QtGui
name, QtCore = _qt_implementation(module)
  File "C:\Users\dm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 437, in _qt_implementation
_qtcore = __import__(name, fromlist=['QtCore']).QtCore
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which GUI library are you actually using in your main script? Your setup script includes files and packages belonging to `tkinter`and `PyQt5`, and the stack trace you've posted shows that the setup script has failed while executing the hook for loading `PyQt4`, which suggests that your main script imports `PyQt4` somewhere. Opt for a single GUI library out of `tkinter`, `PyQt4` and `PyQt5` and use only the chosen one throughout your main and setup scripts.

Comment: @jpeg You are right. UNinstalling PyQt4 solved the problem.

Comment: Sounds great. I've added a corresponding answer with a further hint. I guess you are using `PyQt5`, you should then probably remove the `os.environ` statements and the `include_files` entries from your setup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup script includes files and packages belonging to `tkinter`and `PyQt5`, and the stack trace you've posted shows that the setup script has failed while executing the hook for loading `PyQt4`, which suggests that your main script imports `PyQt4` somewhere. Opt for a single GUI library out of `tkinter`, `PyQt4` and `PyQt5` and use only the chosen one throughout your main and setup scripts.

You can add the libraries you are not using to an `'excludes'` list item in the `build_exe` options dictionary to tell `cx_Freeze` not to include them.